# T-SQL return table ordered by largest pairs first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
id  carrots     potatoes
1   10          0
2   0           5
3   0           0
4   15          3
5   13          2
```

I want to look at customers who ordered both carrots and potatoes. Like this:

```
id  carrots     potatoes
4   15          3
5   13          2
1   10          0
2   0           5
3   0           0
```

I am currently using an ORDER BY where both fields are DESC: `ORDER BY potatoes DESC, carrots DESC`

The problem is that this isn't always reliable. Right now it works, but in the case of a customer who ordered a lot of potatoes and no carrots, if I arbitrarily switch the order to `ORDER BY potatoes DESC, carrots DESC` it gives back

```
id  carrots     potatoes
2   0           5
4   15          3
5   13          2
1   10          0
3   0           0
```

What would your approach be?

Code at sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60763/2. T-SQL/Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: Notice how your sample data includes only rows where carrots always exceeds potatoes if it is not zero. Be careful about how you structure your sample data to validate your logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
order by (case when carrots > 0 then 1 else 0 end) + (case when potatoes > 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc
```

Or, if that is too much typing:

```
order by sign(carrots) + sign(potatoes) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do sum :

```
order by carrots + potatoes desc
```